# Prolog Set of and Length predicate

Tags: prolog

Im trying to work on this prolog rule which is Given a star, check whether he or she is linked with three different movies. If true, return the name of the movies, else return false.

database:

```
starsin(spiderman,tom_holland).
starsin(captain_america,tom_holland).
starsin(avengers,tom_holland).
starsin(parasite,kang_ho).
```

I tried using set of function in my rule which is:

```
checkStarinMovie(Star,Movie):-setof(X,starsin(X,Star),Movie).


% to the the rule write this in the query: checkStarinMovie(tom_holland,Movie).
```

but it would only return the list of movies that the star is in.
I want to be conditional that the star need to be in 3 movies or over. So in this case the star "kang_ho" will return false if you run in the query.

Is there anyway I could use length predicate to set a condition of the rule?

Comment: Check out the latest Prolog question by entering tag `[prolog]` in the Stackoverflow search box. There have been quite a few questions about movies and stars lately.

Comment: `s/Movie/Movies/`, add `Movies = [_,_,_|_],`